# how to Tee in a fuel pressure gauge to line on 2009 toyota corolla

Tags: fuel-system, measurement, fuel-pressure

Does anyone have experience teeing a fuel pressure gauge into the fuel line of a 2009 toyota corolla (specifically 1.8L) ?  The 2010 model is virtually identical.

The service manual says to connect it to the fuel main tube.  It also lists a tee connector to use, but this tee connector seems to be very expensive ... around $70.

I'm not sure, I think the fuel main tube is a rubber hose that connects to a pipe near the gas tank below the vehicle, and then connects behind the engine block to the pipe that feeds the fuel rail.

If I Tee the fuel pressure gauge between the pipe off the gas tank and the rubber fuel main tube, I think it might be hard to find a connector to fit the pipe there.

If I tee between the fuel main tube and the pipe that feeds the fuel rail, that seems easier because the rubber tube appears to just slip over the end of that pipe.  But I'm not sure i can pull it off the pipe, I havent tried yet, and also it's hard to get to because its behind the engine block.

If someone has actually done this you can tell me exactly where to put it and save me a lot of trouble.

Comment: You're positive there's no Schrader valve?

Comment: By schrader valve do you maen a port on the fuel rail ?  On my fuel rail i only see the point where the pipe screws on with some kind of connector.  Again that pipe connects to a rubber hose (main fuel tube i guess) just behind. the engine block

Comment: If it's soft rubber line, you can get a barbed T connector and just clamp it in place. If hard plastic nylon line, you need to heat it with a heat gun until it's pliable, then slip the lines into it. In either case a barbed brass T connector should work. Just be sure it's properly sized, and ideally do it in a section of hose which is easy to replace should you wish to remove the gauge in the future.

Comment: the_storyteller are you suggesting cutting the non-metal part of the fuel line and then teeing into the 2 sides ?  This is what is done here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_Fn7BWcq8Y . He leaves it in permanently.  I'm OK with this approach if it's safe.

Comment: @kinidkinid, yes, exactly like is shown in that video.

Comment: Evidently Toyota makes adapters to connect fuel line pressure gauge>>>https://www.toyotaguru.us/engine-control-systems/fuel-pressure-and-volume-testing.html

Comment: A bluetooth / wireless OnBoard Diagnostics (OBDii) sender unit is around $20  I'm pretty sure fuel pressure is a display input there.  On one hand you could add a T fitting and a gauge or additional sender (with a risk of a fuel leak later on the engine, not clever) or you could have a continuous fuel pressure feedback via a mobile phone app. You can monitor the fuel pressure from inside the vehicle while driving (something difficult to do with a T connected pressure gauge) Less dollars, increased safety, more information, reduced risk.  Where are you going here? What is the ultimate goal?